# Is it possible to find a cell by contents in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to find cells (as a Range) that contain a given text. Is that possible to do ? I'd like to be able to find the first cell matching the text (following the natural order on rows and columns).

Then, a more advanced question, could I provide a Regex to do the same ?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Find seems the obvious answer to the first part of your question.  With Find you can search for text (with or without wild cards) or formats.  You can search by row or columns, forward or backwards.  Go to VB Editor and request help on Find Method.

Comment: Thanks Tony, seems like this is something great for classic text search.

Comment: Alternative to Help. Fill a worksheet with mixed data, including strings created by formula, different colours, different alignments, etc. Switch on the macro recorder and use Ctrl+F to try out some finds. Check the effect of looking for Values or Formula on its success at finding strings. The macro recorder is essential for finding out how to use the less obvious facilities.

Comment: indeed, I didn't think of that ! See my answer below where I quote the output if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample code. Replace `Range("A1:D10")` with your range, and replace the regular expression pattern ni function RE6 with your own.

```
Sub SUB1()
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells
        If RE6(c.Value) Then 
             c.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
        END IF
    Next
End Sub

    Function RE6(strData As String) As String 
        Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object 

        Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 
        With RE 
            .MultiLine = False 
            .Global = False 
            .IgnoreCase = True 
            .Pattern = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" 
        End With 

        Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData) 
        RE6 = REMatches(0) 

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding this to Jerome's answer but I can't until my change is peer reviewed.  20 hours later nothing has happened so I am adding it as an answer.

Don't forget to tidy the macro recorder's output.  Find returns a Range which will be Nothing if the find fails.  FindNext will loop unless you include code to stop this.  You need something like the following:

```
Dim ColFind As Integer
Dim RngFind As Range
Dim AddrFirst As String
Dim RowFind As Integer

With ActiveSheet
  ' Cells can be replaced by any range, for example: Row(5), Columns(3)
  ' The After cell must be in the search range.  It will be the last cell searched.
  ' Get the With dots on the search range and the after cell to match or
  ' you will get some very peculiar results.
  ' What can be, for example: "Th*" to find "The", "There", "Therefore", etc.
  ' or "Th??" to find "Them", "That", etc.
  Set RngFind = .Cells.Find( ... LookIn:=xlValues, After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext ...)
  If RngFind Is Nothing Then

    ' Code to handle failure

  Else
    AddrFirst = RngFind.Address
    Do
      ColFind = RngFind.Column
      RowFind = RngFind.Row

      ' Code to handle found cell

      ' Use FindPrevious if the Search direction is xlPrevious if
      ' you want the cells to be found in sequence.
      ' Warning. I have found that if the Set is omitted, this statement
      ' overwrites the value of the first cell found with the value
      ' of the second cell found.   
      Set RngFind = .Cells.FindNext(RngFind)
    Loop While AddrFirst <> RngFind.Address
  End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells.Find(What:=".GDAXI", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
```

That's a macro recording of what happens when Ctrl F is used, followed by the Find Next feature.